# How do you modify Sitefinity's breadcrumb control?

Tags: breadcrumbs, sitefinity

I need to modify sitefinity's breadcrumbs from this:

**Home**

to this:

**Home >**

So if the breadcrumb is on the root page, it needs to have the > after it.
Im an absolute beginner, so go easy on me! (using version 3.7)

Regards 
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past and solved it by creating a custom user control with the breadcrumb control embedded within it. this allows you to add your own custom logic in the code behind to show or hide things as necessary:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="BreadcrumbControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_Internal_BreadcrumbControl" %>  
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sfweb" Namespace="Telerik.Cms.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Cms.Web.UI"  %>  

    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkHome" runat="server" NavigateUrl="/" Text="My Home Page" /> &raquo;    
    <sfweb:Breadcrumb ID="bCrumb" runat="server" PathSeparator=" » " />
```

here you can hide the BreadCrumb on the home page, showing the homepage hyperlink, which you can customize to show whatever you need.

There may be a better way to do this, but this was the fastest, easiest way I could figure out to do it.

hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the mockup separator. You need to edit the Breadcrumb, click on the advanced button and find the **NodeSeparatorMarkup** field.

In my case I've put >> instead of >

`<span class='sfBreadcrumbNodeSeparator'>&raquo;</span>;`